# After updating to mongodb 2.2.0 findAndModify query gives error message for '$'positional operator

Tags: mongodb

The same query works fine with mongodb 2.0.6.  After updating it to 2.2.0 gives an error and not performing the operation.

```
"errmsg" : "exception: can't append to array using string field name [$]"
```

This occurs at the following line:

```
db.findAndModify(query, null, null, false, updateJob, true, false);
```

where the query is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectID , "job" : { "$elemMatch" : { "jobId" : "1"}}}
```

and `updateJob` is:

```
{ "$set" : { "job.**$**.endTime" : { "$date" : "2012-09-05T04:12:44.708Z"}}
```

**
My Test collection is as below and I want to update my first job and set the new endtime.

```
{
  "_id" : "5f6761d1-589a-4140-9753-5e890ab3ecb9", 

  "name" : "Test",

  "lastJobId" : 2,

  "job" : [{
      "jobId" : "1",

      "jobName" : "test1", 

      "endTime" : ISODate("2012-09-07T17:39:43.032Z"), 

    }, {
      "jobId" : "2",

      "jobName" : "test2", 

      "endTime" : ISODate("2012-09-07T17:39:43.838Z"),      
    }]
}
```

and query used for this is :

```
{  findandmodify :  "Test", query : { _id : "5f6761d1-589a-4140-9753-5e890ab3ecb9", job : { $elemMatch : { jobId : "1" } } }, update : {  $set :  { job.$.endTime :  new  Date(1347039583032) } ,  new : true }
```

Comment: also it would be helpful if you cut and paste the actual command and all definitions - this is not legal syntax in the shell so our answers may not be correct for your actual problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. i haven't tried on update. but another query on update works fine.  Query in shell form { findandmodify: "Test", query: { _id: "6bfe653c-10b2-49c2-b4e7-c26350d886dd", job: { $elemMatch: { jobId: "1" } } }, update: { $set: { job.$.endTime: new Date(1346914611104)}, new: true }

Comment: I tried working s update and it works, but I want my operations atomic so I need to use findandmodify to acquire a lock which doesn't work with 2.2.0.

Comment: You need quotes around "job.$.endTime" otherwise you'll get a syntax error.  Are you sure you are using exactly the same syntax that worked before?  It works fine for me.  By the way, you don't need $elemMatch since you are only matching a single embedded field.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I can run the same command on 2.1 fine, but not on 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectID , "job" : { "$elemMatch" : { "jobId" : "1"}}}
```

does not require the use of "$elemMatch".  $elemMatch is specifically for the case where you are trying to match several fields inside of an array element.

Since you only have one, you can eliminate $elemMatch and just use {"job.jobId":"1"} as the query filter along with "_id" and then your findAndModify will work fine.

There is a bug that prevents findAndModify with $elemMatch and positional operator update from working properly in 2.2 which is filed [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6993).